# Multiple Users on Apache and Linux and Invalid permissions

Tags: permissions, redhat, apache-2.4

I have a RedHat setup with Apache and multiple users.  I gave each user a dir in /var/www/html to host their sites.  Sites are served, but cannot write files (eg. log files, uploads, cache files).  I have all the users as members of the group apache and the dir's have write access for the group.  Anything that I am forgetting to do here?

EDIT: Adding some details.
Apache runs as 'apache' with group 'apache'.  All the users are in the apache group, as the user apache is in the users groups.

Comment: You're forgetting to include your apache config, including the information about which user/group apache runs as, and a directory listing of a directory where file writes fail.

Comment: Is SELinux in enforcing mode? Are log files in their own directories or centrally stored? How are files uploaded? FTP or through the site? What sort of cache files are you talking about?

Comment: Some of our apps are built in Symfony, and there is a built in cache in the framework.  the log/cache files are in the respective dirs for the applications, eg /var/www/html/user/symfony/var/cache|logs.  And users have SSH access to edit the files directly.  This is for a dev server.

Comment: I completly forgot SELinux.  Yes, it is setup as enforcing

Answer (score -1):

I changed my SELinux to 'permissive' instead of 'enforcing' then restarted the server.  Works now.